# Generating a set of N random convex disjoint 2D polygons with at most V vertices, and two additional points?

Tags: reactjs, algorithm, random, polygon

I want to create a set of N random convex disjoint polygons on a plane where each polygon must have at most V vertices, where N and V are parameters for my function, and I'd like to obtain a distribution as close as possible to uniform (every possible set being equally probable). Also I need to randomly select two points on the plane that either match with one of the vertices in the scene or are in empty space (not inside a polygon).

I already implemented for other reasons in the same programming language an AABB tree, Separating Axis Theorem-based collision detection between convex polygons and I can generate a random convex polygon with arbitrary amount of vertices inside a circle of given radius. My best bet thus far:

1. Generate a random polygon using the function I have available.
2. Query the AABB tree to test for interception with existing polygons.
3. If the AABB tree query returns empty set I push the generated polygon into it, otherwise I test with SAT against all the other polygons whose AABB overlaps with the generated one's. If SAT returns "no intersection" I push the polygon, otherwise I discard it.
4. Repeat from 1 until N polygons are generated.
5. Generate a random number in {0,1}
6. If the generated number is 1 I pick a random polygon and a random vertex on it as a point
7. If the generated number is 0 I generate a random position in (x,y) and test if it falls within some polygon (I might create a tiny AABB around it and exploit the AABB tree to reduce the required number of PiP tests). In case it's not inside any polygon I approve it as a valid point, otherwise I repeat from 5.
8. Repeat from 5 once more to get the second point.

I think the solution would possibly work, but unfortunately there's no way to guarantee that I can generate N such polygons for very large N, or find two good points in an acceptable time, and I'm programming in React, where long operations run on the main thread blocking the UI till they end. I could circumvent the issue by ejecting from `create-react-app` and learn Web Workers, which would require probably more time than it's worth for me.

Comment: That's analogous to the packing problem.  It's np-hard (to make it a uniform distribution).  What's the application?  Perhaps the constraints could be relaxed a little?  Also what's the domain for placement: A unit square?

Comment: @Wyck: I coded some algorithms to find the shortest path with disjoint convex polygonal obstacles on a plane as part of an university project. Now I have to test them and compare their performances. My best bet would be to test all of them 30 or so times with 2 random obstacles, repeat with 3, 4, 5 and so on, and then for each algorithm and obstacles count, average the runtime, memory usage, frontier and explored list size.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely non-uniform distribution, but perhaps you could begin by generating N points in the plane and then computing the Voronoi diagram for those points.  The Voronoi diagram can be computed in O(n log n) time with [Fortune's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm).  The cells of the Voronoi diagram are convex, so you can then construct a random polygon of the desired number of vertices that lies within each cell of the diagram.

[image: 20 points and their Voronoi cells]

<sup>By [Balu Ertl](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Balu.ertl) - Own work, [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=38534275)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to control the number of points I have to generate to obtain a given amount of convex polygons? It appears at least in this case that there's exactly as many polygons as there are points, is it general?

Comment: You get one cell per point, always.  Provided the points are not coincident, of course.

Comment: But they aren't disjoint!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is another proposal. I have little knowledge of js, but could cook up something in Python.

1. Use Poisson disk sampling with distance parameter d to generate N samples of the centers
2. For a given center make a circle with R≤d.
3. Generate V angles using Dirichlet distribution such that sum of angles is equal to 2π. Sort them.
4. Place vertices on the circle using angles generate at step#3 and connect them. This would be be your polygon

UPDATE

Instead using Poisson disk sampling for step 1, one could use Sobol quasi-random sequences. For N points sampled in the 1x1 box (well, you have to scale it afterwards), least distance between points would be

d = 0.5 * sqrt(D) / N,

where D is dimension of the problem, 2 in your case. So radius of the circle for step 2 would be 0.25 * sqrt(2) / N. This ties nicely N and d.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378475406002382

Comment: Nice proposition, it sounds pretty reasonable. My biggest concern is that even for small N I'm forced to respect the constraint $R\leq d$ which is OK but it could severely limit the possible polygons especially if d is small. What's a good criteria for picking the d parameter given the amount N of polygons I want to generate?

Comment: @NickTheFreak97 Frankly, I don't know what to choose for (N,V,d) parameters, this is domain specific knowledge. I would say you might want to try doing your tests (graphs) with something like "filling value" vs utility function. Filling ratio being ratio of sum of polygons areas (N and d dependent) divided by your whole box area. I've added another way to select polygon centers, please check update